# Custom NAS, Webserver, and general personal server, What OS?

Tags: nas, samba

im looking to put one of my old desktops to use, it will mostly be used as a NAS, it needs to support SAMBA, but i would also like it if i could also host my webserver on it and later on use it as a bitcoin miner to control the miners etc, what OS would be best for this, is this even possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The common OS in use for web server systems is Linux as part of the Linux, Apache, MySQL, and PHP (LAMP) stack. Linux comes in many distributions, and the most popular for this application is Ubuntu. If you could get Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) that would be ideal, but I doubt you need that kind of power.